# Set the same color filter on png with different colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of icons in .png format, but their colors are different and not the same.

Is there a way to set a specific filter color in css which will transform all my png icons to  the same color?

Like orange will become purple and green will become also purple ?

Comment: The closest I can think of is CSS filter ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter ) but that's quite limiting in browser support. Really this is a job for an image editing tool before you upload them. If you want them to transition, then having two images and faking the transition with opacity would be much more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how you could use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to achieve this (The colours aren't a perfect match, but I didn't want to spend hours tweaking it):

```css
.orange:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(250deg) brightness(110%);
}

.green:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(160deg) brightness(70%);
}
```

```html
<img class="orange" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8AQMAAAAAMksxAAAABlBMVEX/////QwAwDvtVAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABZJREFUeF5joAeQ/w8EB2jCGGXQDgAANDq9XmH0sIEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
<img class="green" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADwAAAA8AQMAAAAAMksxAAAABlBMVEX///8I/wDI9X+0AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAABZJREFUeF5joAeQ/w8EB2jCGGXQDgAANDq9XmH0sIEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" />
```

However, this is not supported by all browsers ([Browser support here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters))

I would personally suggest that you edit the images before uploading them, and if you require some sort of transition, use two images and transition between them using opacity.

Comment: thank u but, i have a lot of icons and i want a solution who will auto set the good hue and brightness depending on png colors

Comment: @Aotoki Is there a reason you can't change them using Photoshop or some other image editing tool before using them?

Comment: editing all the images with photoshop one by one is a monstrous waste of time for not much ..., thanks anyway for your help

Comment: You can use an "action" (which is essentially a macro) to do this automatically in PS. At least that's what they used to be called. You define it once and then tell it to run on a folder of images. Works like a charm for repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with "filter" as pointed in comment and in the previous answer. Since you have many colors in your icons you will need apply a different filter to each icon or... aply two filters: the first one to make them all the 'same color', and the second to "colorize" them again to get the desired color.

```
filter: sepia(100%) hue-rotate(90deg);
```

Anyway this will depend on the support for your target browsers.

You can do the same in your image editing software: make image grayscale, and then edit the color curves to get the color you want.